# Sysprep.exe and Unattend.xml - automatic application of product key not working

Tags: windows-10, automation, product-key, sysprep, unattended

My goal is to automate the OOBE process (launched by sysprep) by removing the need for a new product key to be entered. I already have a product key since I am launching this through sysprep. I would be fine with skipping the step completely since the system is already active. However, I thought it might be easier to just provide the product key already in use on the system.

I am using sysprep for the first time. I have saved an unattend.xml file in the sysprep folder. I tried to make it as simple as possible. My file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="specialize">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup"
     processorArchitecture="amd64"
     publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"
     language="neutral"
     versionScope="nonSxS"
     xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <ProductKey>xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx</ProductKey>
    </component>
    </settings>
</unattend>
```

To generate this I looked at the Microsoft documentation here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732280%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

However, this didn't work. I saw no change from the regular OOBE, and the screen prompting me for a product key was still displayed.

I launched sysprep using `sysprep.exe /oobe /reboot /unattend:unattend.xml` with my unattend.xml stored in the `C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep` directory. I also executed the command from that directory.

I have also browsed several topics on StackExchange, and while many exist that relate to the unattend file, most are very old or do not pertain to applying a product key.

**My question**

How can I use the unattend.xml file to either automatically apply a key or to skip the application of a key during an OOBE initiated by sysprep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help you

```
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP-UX" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SkipAutoActivation>true</SkipAutoActivation>
</component>
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP-UX" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SkipAutoActivation>true</SkipAutoActivation>
</component>
```

Or try using generator: http://windowsafg.no-ip.org/win10x86_x64.html